# QWebview: Turn off loading images at QWebview qt

Tags: c++, image, qt, qwebview

Is there any way to prevent the loading of images with the QWebview in qt?

I load with the QWebview a page with a lot of pictures, so it takes a long time until the page has fully loaded. But I only need the text below the pictures, but I have to wait until the pictures have loaded. Is there any way to prevent loading the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QWebSettings` has an attribute for [autoloading](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwebsettings.html#WebAttribute-enum) images. it's enabled by default so you will have to disable it.

```
poWebView->page()->settings()->setAttribute(
                    QWebSettings::AutoLoadImages,false);
```